# Настройка exernal ip для proftpd в докере

Tags: ftp, docker

Есть докер, есть контейнер с proftpd. Демон ftp настроен на работу в пассивном режиме, запуск контейнера - с помощью docker-compose в котором настроен проброс портов с хост машины. При работе в пассивном режиме (если ftp находится за NAT) нужно указывать внешний IP хост машины в конфиге в переменной MasqueradeAddress.

Проблема в том, что заранее неизвестно, где будет запущен этот контейнер, и сколько внешних IP адресов будет на хост машине. Как быть?

Comment: просто к слову: по протоколу http можно отдавать содержимое файлов, насколько я знаю, ничуть не менее эффективно, чем по протоколу ftp. а проблемы, присущие ftp «by design», отсутствуют.

Comment: требуется не только отдача файлов, но и загрузка, при этом с авторизацией по ldap, доступы у всех пользователей разные

Comment: sshfs, оно же sftp, оно же winscp. вкупе с [sftp chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) — на мой взгляд, неплохое и безопасное (в отличие от ftp) решение.

Comment: к сожалению, требования использовать FTP+TLS ( не sftp )

Comment: попробуйте ознакомить заказчика с вот этим [документом](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Comment: @TheSpbra1n, ну а если просто не задавать жесткий MasqueradeAddress? Он же, по идее, тогда просто будет возвращать клиенту тот IP, на который данный клиент обратился?

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov если не задавать этот адрес, то клиенту отдается внутреннний IP контейнера

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, требования есть требования. Они уже есть, на них автор уже согласился, и их придется выполнять. Требовать на данном этапе заказчика "отказаться нафиг от FTP" уже поздно - это надо было делать ещё на этапе оценки требований.

Comment: @TheSpbra1n, ну это если в бридже. А если для сети контейнера поставить Host Mode? Или на одной хост-машине может быть сразу несколько контейнеров с proftpd?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, то, что не следовало соглашаться на ftp на этапе оценки, это понятно. надеюсь, автор извлечёт полезный урок.

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov , буду пробовать

Comment: @alexander barakin, иногда автор - просто работник, который не участвует в этапах оценки

Comment: @TheSpbra1n, я, конечно, не знаю той ситуации, в которой вы оказались, но, мне кажется, невозможность реализовать какое-то из требований задачи без смены одной из технологий — это вполне разумное основание для внесения корректировки в задачу.

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov,  большое спасибо! Добавил в "docker-compose.yml" строчку `net: "host"` и убрал указание MasqueradeAddress , на виртуалке такое решение заработало ( правда отвалились link в docker-compose , но эта проблема решается еще проще.

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov, не знаю как пометить ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @TheSpbra1n, оформил как ответ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на хосте будет не более одного контейнера с proftpd - можете просто сменить у вашего контейнера тип сети с "bridge" на "host", и убрать MasqueradeAddress в конфиге proftpd.

Так контейнер будет использовать сеть хост-машины, а proftpd пассивным клиентам будет отдавать тот ip, на который они пытаются подключится.